# solve a tricky equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I created a problem and i am looking for help in solving this equation. I do not know if any method exists except numerical methods. I tried to transform this equation to solve with Lambert W function but unsuccessfully.

$$x^{x+3}=125$$

Comment: Taking [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1794027/597568) at its word, equations of this type cannot be solved with the Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: Maybe a method like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666233/solution-for-x-of-y-abxx/4666453#4666453) would work. Also, how is this linear-algebra?

Comment: This was a welcoming gift to you. Next time, please, show you work (even if you failed) and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^{x+3}=125$$
$$e^{\ln(x)(x+3)}=125$$
$$\ln(x)(x+3)=3\ln(5)$$
$$\ln(x)\ x+3\ln(x)=3\ln(5)$$

We see, this equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($\ln(x),x$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$x\to e^t$:
$$te^t+3t=3\ln(5)$$
$$te^t=3\ln(5)-3t$$
$$\frac{t}{3\ln(5)-3t}e^t=1$$

We see, we cannot solve this equation in terms of Lambert W, but in terms of Generalized Lambert W.

$$\frac{t}{t-\ln(5)}e^t=-3$$
$$t=W\left(^{\ \pm 0}_{\ln(5)};-3\right)$$
$$x=e^{W\left(^{\ \pm 0}_{\ln(5)};-3\right)}$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 1):

If you make the problem more general, you are looking for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x^{x+a}-b$$ which does not look very nice.

Better would be to consider instead
$$g(x)=(x+a)\log(x)-\log(b)$$ Expanding as series around $x=1$
$$(x+a)\log(x)=(1+a)(x-1)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac{1-a(n-1) }{n(n-1)}\,(x-1)^n$$

Use power series reversion to obtain
$$x=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{P_n(a)}{n!\, (a+1)^{2n-1}} \log^n(b)$$ where the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(a) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & a-1 \\
 3 & a^2-7 a+4 \\
 4 & a^3-25 a^2+67 a-27 \\
 5 & a^4-71 a^3+531 a^2-821 a+256 \\
 6 & a^5-181 a^4+3046 a^3-11606 a^2+12281 a-3125 \\
 7 & a^6-435 a^5+14666 a^4-113366 a^3+273141 a^2-217015 a+46656  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For your specific example $(a=3,b=125)$, as a function of the order, the results are oscillating (which is not very good) and convergence is quite slow
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 1 & 2.20708 \\
 2 & 2.57134 \\
 3 & 2.42477 \\
 4 & 2.39160 \\
 5 & 2.45300 \\
 6 & 2.44078 \\
 7 & 2.41835 \\
 8 & 2.43447 \\
 9 & 2.43869 \\
 10 & 2.42791 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Probably better would be to use the very first iteration of any Newton-like method of order $n$ using
$$x_0=1+\frac{\log(b)}{a+1}$$ This will give fully explicit formulae.

For your example
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_1^{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 & 2.43115 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 & 2.43245 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 & 2.43225 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 & 2.43226 & \text{no name} \\
 6 & 2.43226 & \text{no name} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$